# List the variables defined in a Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I want to get the list of all the variables defined in a Python module, without the imported variables. With classes or functions, it can be done with `inspect.getmembers`, for example:

```py
getmembers(module, lambda member: isclass(module) and member.__module__ == module.__name__)
```

However, simple objects don't seem to have the `__module__` field, so I can't check if they have been imported or have been defined in the module directly.

If I restrict the user from using `from ... import` statements, and only use `__init__.py` files which don't import simple variables it can work, since it is not possible to import them, but it is not a satisfying solution...

Is there a way to list variables defined in a Python module, excluding imported ones ?